# Javascript data from foreach in php.

Tags: javascript, php

Related to my previous question:
[How to use javascript load function twice? (load in load)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308310/how-to-use-javascript-load-function-twice-load-in-load)

I've got everything working (load in load). But now I want to use a foreach which sends data to the second load.

When I use this foreach the data (POST ID) remains the same.

Example code:

```
<script >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Forum categories
        $("#main").on("click", "#message", function () {
            $("#getmessage").load("forum/getmessage.php", {'id': $("#id").val()});
        });
    });
</script >

<?php foreach($stickies as $sticky): ?>
                <form id="form_id" >
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item small" id="message"
                       style="background-color:black; color:white;" >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true" ></span >
                        | <?php echo $sticky['header']; ?>
                    </a >

                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $sticky['id']; ?>" >

                </form >
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can see I'd like to push the value ID as POST data, so the loaded file can perform a query on this POST ID.

How can I send the correct ID for every foreach?

Comment: Start with understanding that id of an element __must be unique__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve what you need. So it's just an example.

First of all - value of `id` attribute **must be unique**. No exceptions. That's why `id="message"` for every `a` and `id="id"` for every `input` are **invalid**. For similar elements - use classes.

Fixed code will be:

```
<?php foreach($stickies as $sticky): ?>
    <form>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item small js-message"
           style="background-color:black; color:white;" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true" ></span >
            | <?php echo $sticky['header']; ?>
        </a >
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $sticky['id']; ?>" >
    </form >
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can see, I removed id attributes with same values. For `input`s and `form`s you don't even need them, for `a`s I added class `js-message`.

Next is handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Forum categories
    $("#main").on("click", ".js-message", function () {
        // ways of getting value id can be different.
        $("#getmessage").load(
            "forum/getmessage.php", 
             {'id': $(this).parent().find("input").val()
        });

        // optionally you can add
        return false;
        // to prevent default click action which in case
        // of link is scrolling to the top of a page
    });
});
```

Here, as one of the ways to get value I used

```
$(this).parent().find("input").val()
```

which is:

```
$(this).parent()    // find a parent of a clicked a, it will be `form`
    .find("input")  // among `form` children find `input`
    .val()          // take value from found input
```

Surely, if your markup will change and more `inputs` will appear on the form, this may stop working. But it's just an example, you can modify this as you want.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much u_mulder. I marked it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are creating many elements with an `id="id"` which is incorrect.  The `id` attribute must be unique per page and therefore your jQuery is only returning the value of the first one found when you use `$("#id").val()`.

Instead add a data attribute to the button which can be retrieved on the click event like this, note I've also removed the `id="message"` and added a message class for the reason noted above and removed the form element as it is not needed:

```
<?php foreach($stickies as $sticky): ?>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item small message"
       style="background-color:black; color:white;" data-id="<?php echo $sticky['id'] ?>">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></span> | <?php echo $sticky['header']; ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>


<script >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Forum categories
        $("#main").on("click", "#message", function () {
            $("#getmessage").load("forum/getmessage.php", {'id': $(this).attr('data-id')});
        });
    });
</script >
```

Comment: `The id attribute must be unique` but you still use `#message`.

Comment: And you'll have multiple forms with `id=form_id`

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your help. I used the code from u_mulder, it worked.